# how to print 2 hashes intercalating the keys?

Tags: perl

Please, I'm initializing 2 hashes by:

```
$hash1{$key} = -9;
$hash2{$key} = -9;
```

Then I get the array @order with the order of the keys:

```
my @order1 = sort {$a cmp $b} keys(%hash1);
my @order2 = sort {$a cmp $b} keys(%hash2);
```

Then I want to print these 2 arrays intercalating the keys. Example: 1º key of 1º hash, 1º key of 2º hash, and so on.

```
print(join("\t", @order1, @order2) . "\n"); #this will print the entire hash1 first and     then the hash 2
```

Please how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use List::MoreUtils qw( pairwise );
say join "\t", pairwise { $a, $b } @order1, @order2;
```